# Implementing Dynamic Method Execution based on Controller Return in Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm facing a challenge with structuring my Spring Framework application. I have a specific scenario where I need to execute different methods based on the return value of a controller method. To provide more context, I have a controller method named ReqFromGate which is annotated with @PostMapping("/mbilling"). This method takes a BillingEntity as a request body and is responsible for handling incoming billing requests.

Here's the simplified version of my controller method:

```
@PostMapping("/mbilling")
public BillingEntity ReqFromGate(@RequestBody BillingEntity billingEntity) {
    // I want to dynamically execute different service methods based on the return type
    // of this method (either account or payment)
}
```

Inside this controller method, I need to determine which of the two service methods (getMbillingForAccount and getMbillingForPayment) should be executed based on the return type of the ReqFromGate method. The return type can either be an "account" or a "payment" type BillingEntity.

Here are the two service methods:

```
public BillingEntity getMbillingForAccount(BillingEntity billingEntity) {
    // Implementation specific to account processing
}

public BillingEntity getMbillingForPayment(BillingEntity billingEntity) {
    // Implementation specific to payment processing
}
```

I'm aiming to achieve dynamic method execution within the ReqFromGate controller method, where the choice of either getMbillingForAccount or getMbillingForPayment is based on the type of BillingEntity returned by the controller. This means that the getMbilling method must be able to reflect the differences in processing between the two cases.

What would be the most effective and cleanest approach to handle this situation while adhering to Spring Framework best practices and guidelines? I appreciate any guidance or insights into how to structure this behavior effectively.

Comment: Could you please share code samples with description to understand the use case

Comment: @R.G thanks for respond. I've edited question for being more clear

Comment: If I understand the question correctly , as long as the consumer of this end point can process the BillingEntity based on what it receives this looks correct.